How to setup text dimension to match the same total lenght for each row
Newbie here. Sorry for bad explaining this, but I literally have no idea which specific terms to use.
I want to build, via html or css, a text slogan whose dimension is the same for each row, basing on an orizontal lenght.
This means, if I have to right the following 2-rows slogan:
FOLLOW YOUR
HEART
The "HEART" row word needs a higher font-size in order to match with "FOLLOW YOUR".
I know it's possibile to handle this manually, but the problem is whatever I arrange on desktop view, will look very different on mobile.
So I guess there must be a tool that automatically arranges the font sizes dynamically.
Maybe a plugin? I'm using wordpress.
Or a CSS?
This is an example: enter image description here
Tried with html code, but font-size itself doesn't work in both desktop and mobile view in the same way.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Hello, okay, my bad. Sorry for having included a plugin name in the question, but I guess "explain a technique" is supposed to be allowed. There must be a CSS trick or html way to arrange it, I'm sure :)

Essentially, no. CSS can't do that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-size-of-container

Using BigText js and combine with FitText js maybe ? First one is fitting text and the other uses scale approach if you dont want to go with @media css. Just alternative. But to answer your question you need dynamic values CSS supports but its not the best way of doing it. So use js instead.
